# Shared Variables and Garbage Collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, garbage-collection

I've been doing some reading on garbage collection in .NET and I was hoping for some clarification. So, as I understand it if I declare a public shared class variable, the GC will never get rid of it. Is this correct?

Also, what then of private variables? Take the following example:

```
public class myClass
    private shared myString As String

    public sub ChangeString(newString As String)
        myString = newString
    end sub
end class
```

Would the shared variable now get GCed if there were no instances of the class? And what if I alter ChangeString to be a shared sub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, as I understand it if I declare a public shared class variable, the GC will never get rid of it. Is this correct?

Almost.  The GC will not clean up the string that your Shared variable references.

If, however, you call `ChangeString` with a new string, the string that was pointed to by `myString` will no longer be rooted by this reference, and may be eligible for GC.  However, the new string (referenced by `newString`) will now become rooted by the `myString` variable, preventing it from garbage collection.

> Would the shared variable now get GCed if there were no instances of the class?

No.  The shared variable roots the object, since it's owned by the "type" of the class, not any instances.

> And what if I alter ChangeString to be a shared sub?

This will have no effect at all.

Answer (score 2):

Static (shared) variables are always considered roots. Thread static (shared) variables are roots for the owning thread. So, whatever these variables refer to will never be cleaned up by the GC.

> Would the shared variable now get GCed if there were no instances of the class?

Thus, if the static constructor is ever invoked, the referent will persist through the relevant lifetime (either the process for static and the thread for thread static). It doesn't matter if there are instances of the class or not, what matters is whether or not the static constructor executed (and this is somewhat non-deterministic, you only know that if any static members are needed, they will be created before the first time that they are needed).

> And what if I alter ChangeString to be a shared sub?

This doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

The shared variable lives in the class itself, so you don't need an instance of the class for the variable to survive, so your string would not be garbage collected.

It doesn't matter if a variable is private, it still won't be garbage collected. It doesn't matter if you use a sharded method or an instance method to set the variable.

Note: The garbage collector never collects *variables*, it only collects objects.

Answer (score 2):

`Shared` variable references are rooted in an app domain. So as long the app domain is still loaded then whatever object is referenced by that variable is still rooted and so the GC will not collect that object regardless of how many instances of the containing class may or may not exist. However, if you change the reference, as could be done with `ChangeString` in your specific example, then the old object would no longer be rooted and would now be eligible for collection.

Again, as long as you are not doing advanced app domain management then any object referenced by `myString` will not be eligible for collection unless, of course, you stop referencing that object by reassinging the `myString` variable.